# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null wordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho vários botões em uma pagina de um site wordPress, eu defini todos esses botões com a classe click, quando o usuário clicar em um dos botões eu tenho que pegar o id do botão clicado, com esse id eu pego o elemento e disparo uma função que abre um modal.
Porem quando testo no navegador ela funciona normalmente no wordPress ela da o seguinte erro: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, por que?

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function iniciaModal(modalID){
        const modal = document.getElementById(modalID);
        if(modal){
            modal.classList.add('mostrar');
        modal.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
            if(e.target.id == modalID || e.target.className == 'fechar'){
                modal.classList.remove('mostrar');
            }
        });
        }
    }   

    $('.click').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        const idButton = document.getElementById(id);
        idButton.addEventListener('click', () => iniciaModal('modal-form-popup'));
    });
})
```

HTML Modal:

```
<div id="modal-form-popup" class="modal-containerPopup">
<div class="modalPopup">
    <button class="fechar">x</button>
    <h3>Teste</h3>
    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-containerPopup{
width:100vw;
height: 100vh;
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
position: fixed; 
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index:1000;
display: none;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}

.modal-containerPopup.mostrar{
display: flex;
}



.modalPopup{
background:white;
width:60%;
padding: 25px;
border: 6px solid  black;
position:relative;

}

@keyframes modal {
from{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
}
to{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
}
.mostrar .modalPopup{
animation: modal .3s;
}

.fechar{
position:absolute;
font-size: 1em;
top:-30px;
right:-30px;
width:30px;
height:30px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 4px solid white;
background: #35baf2;
color: white;
box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
cursor: pointer;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: O método getElementById retorna null quando não encontra nenhum elemento. O que significa que o seu elemento de classe "click" não possui nenhum atributo do tipo id: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: @RicardoPassos valeu Ricardo, era isso mesmo sou muito inexperiente com wordPress

Comment: @RicardoPassos pode me da uma dica agr está tudo funcionando mas, estou precisando dar dois clicks no botão pq disparei  quando clica na classe, dps quando ele pega o elemento com aquele id pra disparar o modal como eu faria tudo com um so click?

Answer (score 1):

### Dada a sua solicitação nos comentários da sua pergunta, dedici criar essa resposta para manter a organização.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const modal = $("#modal-form-popup");
  const botaoAbrirModal = $(".click");
  const botaoFecharModal = $(".fechar");
  
  function abreFechaModal() {
    modal.toggleClass('mostrar');
  }

  botaoAbrirModal.click(function () {
    abreFechaModal();
  });

  botaoFecharModal.click(function () {
    abreFechaModal();
  })
});
```

```css
.modal-containerPopup{
width:100vw;
height: 100vh;
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
position: fixed; 
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index:1000;
display: none;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}

.modal-containerPopup.mostrar{
display: flex;
}

.modalPopup{
background:white;
width:60%;
padding: 25px;
border: 6px solid  black;
position:relative;

}

@keyframes modal {
from{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
}
to{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
}
.mostrar .modalPopup{
animation: modal .3s;
}

.fechar{
position:absolute;
font-size: 1em;
top:-30px;
right:-30px;
width:30px;
height:30px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 4px solid white;
background: #35baf2;
color: white;
box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
cursor: pointer;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="click">Abrir modal</button>

<div id="modal-form-popup" class="modal-containerPopup">
<div class="modalPopup">
    <button class="fechar">x</button>
    <h3>Teste</h3>
    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Alguns pontos a serem observados:

1. A sua div de id ***modal-form-popup*** não possuia uma tag de fechamento, isso foi corrigido do código acima
2. Você estava misturando jQuery com JavaScript puro. Sempre opte por usar um ou outro, nunca ambos. Assim você mantem consistência no seu código. Se não souber fazer algo, simplesmente leia a documentação do jQuery ou procure na internet.

Explicação do script: toda vez que o botão de abrir modal ou fechar modal é clicado, a função abreFechaModal é disparada e o método toggleClass faz a lógica de adicionar/remover a classe. Se a classe 'mostrar' **não existir** no elemento 'modal', o toggleClass() **adiciona** essa classe. Se a classe **existir**, ele a **remove**.

Referência: https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou seguir suas sugestões sou iniciante as vezes faço gambiarra pra funcionar.